# Zfs file system with two roots that can be selected at boot

Tags: ubuntu, grub, zfs

I have Ubuntu 20.10 on zfs root (upgraded from 20.04)
I tried to restore 20.04 using zsys features at boot, which was unsuccessful.
I have a backup (created using syncoid). Using zfs send/receive. I created a new pool in a separated disk called spool. It has a restored 20.04 before the upgrade.

I'd like to be able to choose at boot time between the two rpools. How to I set it up with grub.

Answer (score 1):

The root is selected using the kernel boot parameter `root=ZFS=pool/fsname`. Simply add another grub entry with a different entry for different root.

Comment: Is there a way  to make "update-grub" do it for me. The file /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs might be a good candidate for modification. I just do not know enough to make the changes.

Comment: I tried  to make the change manually. It fails to mount spool (the new rpool). It tied to mount it the root from spool on /root/spool/ROOT.. instead of /

Comment: I suspect you forgot to set mount point=legacy on spool/ROOT.

Comment: If I do that. I do not think that all the subpools and the user pools will be mounted.

Comment: They aren't directly related. The root file system gets mounted by the initramfs under /sysroot during the initramfs stage. The other file systems get mounted after switchroot by systems via the zfs-import-cache and zfs-import-scan services.

Comment: I was finally able to do it. It is not a clean solution.  I set the pool to legacy, which automatically sets all the sub-pools to legacy. Then I mounted the sub-pools at boot with /etc/fstab. I discovered that /usr and /var are not mounted subpools only some of their sub-directories  are. I do not like this solution. I wish that grub/zfs would be more flexible, I think that modification to  /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs is needed.

Comment: In fairness, having the entire /usr and /var on non-root file system is supported on most distros these days, that setup is from the dark ages of Unix back in the early '90s.